# How to get out of 2D view

Tags: 3d-view

I created some UV spheres and my work progressed nicely. At some point I inadvertently must have pressed some button and I see only flat black circles instead of spheres. Also the sidebar shows that the Dimension setting for the z-Axis is 0. Any other value I enter here is ignored.

[image: screenshot]

---

I have chosen top orthographic view on purpose. Changing to user perspective does not solve the problem. Tilted user perspective looks like this

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Oh, I see. So those are supposed to be 3D? That's strange... I'm looking into it, but i'll admit, I've never seen anything like that before.

Comment: Hi. If you need to reply to a user you can use the comment box below their answer instead of editing their answer. I have undone your edit to the answer below and added an edit to the question to include the information. If you still need to comment on Christopher Bennett's answer, use the comment box below it. Thanks.

Comment: The CLOSEST I can find to people having similar issues to you has to do with rotation/scale not being applied, but I don't know if that will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Ray Mairlot. I could not figure out how to add an image in the comment box. Therefore I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, your hint solved the problem in the end. Some of the Bezier curves which are used as the targets for the follow path constraint  of the spheres had a z-axis value of 0 in the scale property.

Comment: Ahhh. Interesting. I thought that might be the case with something, but in the image you provided, it shows a z-scale of 0.200 so I dismissed it.  Glad you found the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have entered orthographic mode. Press <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> to toggle it on and off, or simply hold down the <kbd>Scroll Wheel</kbd> and move the mouse you will be out of it. If you want to use orthographic modes in the future:

<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> = front orthographic

<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> = side orthographic

<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> = top orthographic

<kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> = flip (ex: top flips to bottom)